# No style on jquery mobile header buttons

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm having this problem with buttons in the jquery mobile header bar.

They appear without style, only the text 'Back' is shown.

I already tried replacing the stylesheets with freshly downloaded ones.

This happens when I add the back button by placing `<a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a>` inside the header div and also when I set this attribute `data-add-back-btn="true"` to the page div.

The page on wich this happens is dynamicly loaded, but when I'm testing it on the index page it also happens.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong? I'm using jquery mobile 1.2.0 in combination with Cordova (PhoneGap).

Comment: Are you viewing this on a phone or in an emulator? If you aren't and you are using a browser then you should inspect your link and see if any of the styles are loading.

Comment: The same problem appears in browser as well as in the iphone simulator. All resources are loaded correctly.

Comment: Do your <a> tags have a css property of display:block; or inline-block; ?

Comment: I have no custom css at all at this point, it's all jquery mobile

Comment: And the style sheet you are using is jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css ?

Comment: Yep, the minified one.. and it are two stylesheets. One called structure and one theme. Theme is loaded after structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data-roles on your link might be wrong.Try adding `data-role="button"` to your link and see what happens. It should look something like this.

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="back">Back</a>
```

Comment: Well that did the trick. Pretty strange though, as I exactly followed the instructions from jquery mobile.

Comment: I have been there. It is easy to miss something in documentation. Glad I could help though.